# how to connect two clients using pygame so they run on the same network and both of the players see each others actions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, client

So i made a game similair to chiken invaders and the goal is to connect two clients so that two players from different pc's can see each others movement etc . I tried to implement that by myself but i failed and the deadline is close . Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: You can check this [very basic Python Multiplayer game prototype](https://github.com/PlainSight/pygameblog)

Comment: from page pygame.org - [Mastermind Networking Lib](http://www.pygame.org/project-Mastermind+Networking+Lib-859-.html)